# Flaticon CSS icon size issue

Tags: css

I started trying to incorporate some icons from http://www.flaticon.com

I got it working but my issue is as I increase the size of the icon more and more of it starts to occupy space outside its container and is thus overlapping some other content or cut off. I have a live link below. I have tweaked everything I can think of in the CSS that could resolve this problem (display, padding, margin) and can't seem to get it to expand its container to house itself without infringing on the element above it. Any ideas would be much appreciated! I have tried so many other libraries for icons and i liked this one the most, so I would really like to find a solution. I find it strange that no one else has come across this same issue, maybe its something else on my page that is interfering with my icons styling?

Link: http://stnatoday.com

Some Images:
(Lower on the page)
[image]
(Higher on the page)
[image]
My CSS

```
@font-face {
     font-family: "Flaticon";
     src: url("flaticon.eot");
     src: url("flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
          url("flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
          url("flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
          url("flaticon.svg") format("svg");
    font-style: normal;
 }
 [class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
 [class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
    font-family: Flaticon;
    font-size: 25em;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-left: 20px;
 }
.flaticon-job-search1:before {
     content: "\e001";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want but when working with fonts the "line-height" property often solves problems (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp)
Maybe you can explain what the desired result should be.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how I didnt think of that, I guess I lost sight of this being a font. You sir are awesome! Thats exactly what I needed!